# What code do I need to change the color of the body outline and wick color in pine editor in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

I found this code shared in the Pine editor in the tradingview website and it does change the color of the body but I'm hopeful someone can show me how to change the wick and body outline color as well.

I tried adding wick _colour = color.yellow and it didn't work. I don't know what to put for body outline.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/    
// © u_20bf    
//@version=5

indicator('Highlight candles by time', overlay=true)

// Inputs    
// TODO: Provide better options

display_timeframes = input.string(title='What timeframes to display ?', defval='M5', options=['M5', 'M15', 'M30','H1' ,'H4'])

// Times need to be the exchange timezone right now (eg +2 from GMT for FXCM)

display_period_one = input.bool(true, 'Display period one?')    
period_one_session = input.session('1600-1900', 'Period one times')    
display_period_two = input.bool(false, 'Display period two?')    
period_two_session = input.session('0800-0900', 'Period two times')    
display_period_three = input.bool(false, 'Display period three?')    
period_three_session = input.session('1200-1300', 'Period three times')

// TODO: Colour per session    
candle_colour = color.yellow

// Checks    
display_on_current_timeframe = display_timeframes == 'M5'    
is_in_session = (display_period_one and time(timeframe.period, period_one_session)) or (display_period_two and time(timeframe.period, period_two_session)) or (display_period_three and time(timeframe.period, period_three_session))    
can_colour_candle = display_on_current_timeframe and is_in_session

// Colouring
barcolor(color=can_colour_candle ? candle_colour : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barcolor()` will only change the color of the bars. If you want to color the whole candle, including the wick, border and body, you need to use the `plotcandle()`.

```
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title, color, wickcolor, editable, show_last, bordercolor, display) → void
```

You then may want to "bring your indicator forward".

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=color.white, wickcolor=color.yellow, bordercolor=color.blue)
```

[image]